# Обмен данными между формами Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

Есть 2 формы, у форм разные классы-контроллеры, 1 форма по нажатию на кнопку загружает другую. Как отправить 2 форме информацию из 1 формы.

Для смены форм использую - есть статический Stage, на котором меняю Scene :

```
 public static Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public  void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    runStage(primaryStage);
}

public static void runStage(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    primaryStage = stage;
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Смена формы по нажатию на кнопку:

```
   public void EditBook() throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/EditBook.fxml"));
    Main.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    Main.primaryStage.show();
}
```

Хотелось бы узнать как правильно менять формы и увидеть на примере взаимодействие между формами

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Взаимодействие между формами можно сделать через вызов методов у контроллера.

Чтобы получить контроллера, надо писать так

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader("/sample/EditBook.fxml");
Parent root = loader.load();
Main.primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
ControllerClass controllerEditBook = loader.getController(); //получаем контроллер для второй формы
controllerEditBook.someMethod(someParameters); // передаем необходимые параметры
Main.primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Спасибо, по полочкам расписана передача параметров. Получается в любой метод класса ControllerClass я могу передать параметры?

Comment: Вы можете вызвать любой метод из ControllerClass