# Передача значений между классами - Java

Tags: java

Подскажите, как грамотно реализовать передачу данных между классами.

В классе А есть переменная, также для этой переменной есть get и set, именно в этом классе нужно установить переменной variable значение 5.

```
class A {
    int variable;
    public A() {
        setVariable(5);
    }
    public void setVariable(int variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    public int getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Далее, есть класс В, в котором есть метод returnVariable где нужно получить значение переменной variable и вывести на экран.

```
class B {
    void returnVariable() {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.getVariable());
    }
}
```

Я знаю что при new A(); создается новая ячейка в памяти, и getVariable() как бы равен 0 или null. Но есть я устанавливаю int static variable; то результат выводит: 5. Скажите, как можно обойтись без статических полей в данном случае?

Comment: У вас я не заметил статических переменных. Вы в конструкторе инициализируете переменную значением 5

Comment: @JVic Да в конструкторе я инициализирую, а в другом классе я вызываю и null ну или 0. В том и дело что я хочу как то реализовать без статических переменных. Если ставлю static, то все хорошо.

Comment: Передавайте значение как параметр конструктора: A a = new A(5);

Comment: У вас сейчас должно все работать без статических переменных. Приведите пример всего кода. И я не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду «я вызываю 0 ну или null»

Comment: @JVic Слушай короче ты JavaFX знаешь? Кстати, в профиле увидел твой город, я тоже с КР :)

Comment: вроде всё и так работает.. ( [пруф](https://ibb.co/ngEQk8) + [код](https://pastebin.com/U3FuhmNy) )

Comment: @OldTeaOwl Нет! Так то работает 6 и 9 выводит у тебя. А именно смотри 14 строку где передается 5, и эту 5 нужно в классе B вывести. И у тебя System.out - 3 штуки, а выводит на скрине только 2.

Comment: @D.Stifler так вроде и вправду должно все работать, вы при инициализации нового объекта А по идеи сразу получаете новый объект А со значением 5.

Можете еще и так сделать конечно : 
`public A() {
        this.variable = 5;
    }`

Comment: @D.Stifler мой промах - скрин старый, но смысл не меняется - вот, всё подновил ([скрин](https://ibb.co/nBitNo) + [код](https://pastebin.com/9QEci99u) )

Comment: хотя.. давай так, @D.Stifler , запусти код, и дай скрин консоли, может, действительно есть какая-то проблема, а мы не знаем?.. (если можешь какие-то логи с доп.информацией прописать, было бы не плохо)

Comment: @OldTeaOwl Ты JavaFX знаешь? Проблема такая как в примере с передачами параметров между контроллерами.

Comment: @D.Stifler боюсь, что отстал от жизни и всё ещё пользуюсь Swing) Но знаешь, вторая же ссылка в гугле похожа на [то, что тебе нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592482/Обмен-данными-между-формами-java-fx?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы реализовать  передачу данных между классами, вам нужно передать ссылку на первый класс второму. Вы это можете сделать в конструкторе
класса B. То есть создать конструктор с параметрами, в которых передается ссылка.

```
public B(A a){
    public B(A a){
    System.out.println(a.getVariable());
    }
    }
```

Вы также можете создать конструктор с параметрами у класса A.
Для того, чтобы сразу, при создании класса устанавливать переменной
новое значение.
Вот пример кода, который я для вас написал. Класс A:

```
package setVarClass;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class A {
    int variable;
    public A() {
        setVariable(5);
    }

    // конструктор с параметрами
    public A(int var){
    this.variable = var;
    }
    public void setVariable(int variable) {
        this.variable = variable;
    }
    public int getVariable() {
        return variable;
    }
}
```

Класс B:

```
package setVarClass;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class B {
    public B(){}
    public B(A a){
    System.out.println(a.getVariable());
    }
    void returnVariable() {
        A a = new A(); // тут создается экземпляр класса A
        System.out.println(a.getVariable());
    }
}
```

Класс для тестирования:

```
package setVarClass;

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class TestVarInClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //  можно не создавать A потому как А создается в конструкторе B();
       // A a= new A();// тут вызываем конструктор без праметром
       // и переменной присваивается хначение по умолчанию = 5
       B b = new B();
       b.returnVariable(); // выводит значение переменной

       A acon = new A(80);
       B b1 = new B(acon);// тут выведет 80
    }
}
```

Строка  `A a = new A(); // тут создается экземпляр класса A`
в методе класса  `void returnVariable()`
лишняя. Теперь вы можете обойтись без неё. Но в этом случае
вы должны передать ссылку на класс в методе returnVariable(),
как я это сделал в конструкторе.